# How can I add validation onto a Date that rolls into another year using Java Date class

Tags: java, date

I'm currently trying to improve an aspect of a project of mine.

Users are allowed to do a specific task, but they must book a date in order to do it.

I'm trying to add some more realistic validation onto my date, so that the tasks can't be booked a year in advance, and only a few months.

Currently I'm only checking the year of the input and comparing it to the current year, so if they try to assign themselves a task on 31st of December, they will not be able to because any date they enter will roll over to the next year, and my validation prevents this.

How can I make it so it will check the amount of months, rather than the current year?

I am able to do this for the current year, I just get stuck when the year comes to december and the months roll into January again.

Edit:
Those looking for a way to fix this, go here: [Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances) question. I guess its similar to what you want

Comment: @IzaazYunus I was just about to post a link to that very question.

Comment: Does that post answer your question?

Comment: Yes thank you very much, I decided to use joda-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the lengths of months are different, I would test the number of *days*. Here's a couple of utility methods that get the job done in one line:

```
// Tests if the end date is within so many days of the start date 
public static boolean isWithinRange(int days,  Date end, Date start) {
    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(end.getTime() - start.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) < days;
}

// Tests if the specified date is within so many days of today 
public static boolean isWithinRange(int days, Date end) {
    return isWithinRange(days, end, new Date());
}
```

Here I've used the `TimeUnit` class to do the calculation for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use your own method. Something like this

```
public boolean isLaterDay(Date date, Date reference) {
    if (date.getYear () > reference.getYear ()) return true;
    if (date.getYear () < reference.getYear ()) return false;
    return (date.getMonth() > reference.getMonth());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this would be as follows.

```
boolean validDate(Calendar inputDate)
{
    Calendar validationDate = Calendar.getInstance().add(Calendar.MONTH, numOfMonths);
    return inputDate.before(validationDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to validate the time

```
private static final int MAX_MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE = 3;

public boolean isValidDate(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, MAX_MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE);
    return date.before(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Joda-Time library:

```
If ( dateTimeInQuestion.isBefore( DateTime.now().plusMonths(3) )
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern way to do this work is with the java.time classes. These classes supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Construct the date desired by the user.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 12 , 31 );
```

Determine the boundaries, say six months ago and six months from now.

```
LocalDate past = today.minusMonths( 6 );
LocalDate future = today.plusMonths( 6 );
```

You can compare `LocalDate` objects with `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `equals`, and `compareTo`.

Let's test by asking if the user's date is equal to or later than the `before` boundary (in other words, not before) AND the user's date is before the `future` boundary. This comparison uses the *Half-Open* approach commonly used with date-time work. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
Boolean validDate = ( ( ! ld.isBefore( past) ) && ( ld.isBefore( future) ) );
```

## `Interval`

If you often work with the spans of time, consider using the [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class found in the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project that adds onto the java.time classes. That class has handy methods such as `contains`, `abuts`, `overlaps`, and more.